# What value each of these classes add in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I know we have following hierarchy of classes in WPF.

```
Visual
    UIElement
        FrameWorkElement
            Control
```

I am interested in finding out what value each of these classes add to make a final UI control for example a `Textbox`. What is significance of each individual class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all of this information within the MSDN documentation.

**Significance of individual elements**

- [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx): Provides rendering support in WPF, which includes hit testing, coordinate transformation, and bounding box calculations.
- [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx): A base class for WPF core level implementations building on Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) elements and basic presentation characteristics.
- [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx): Provides a WPF framework-level set of properties, events, and methods for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) elements.
- [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx): Represents the base class for user interface (UI) elements that use a ControlTemplate to define their appearance.
- [TextBoxBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.aspx): An abstract base class that provides functionality for text editing controls.
- [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx): Represents a control that can be used to display or edit unformatted text.

**Finding out what value each of these classes add to make a final UI control**

If you take a look at the [TextBox properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_properties.aspx), you will see in the descriptions of properties that are provided by elements higher hierarchy text like this:

> (Inherited from {Element Name})

Reviewing the properties of the TextBox control will allow you to determine how it is composed from the inheritance hierarchy through inheritance.

Comment: `(Inherited from {Element Name})` this line will solve all my confusions thanks.